# Material UI & Styled Component Overriding Issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, material-ui, styled-components

I was using Material UI's Typography and it worked perfectly:

```
 <Typography component="h1" variant="h5">
          Sign in
        </Typography>
```

However, I wanted to move to styled-components so I tried using this:

```
export const Typo = styled(Typography)`
    component: h1;
    variant: h5;
`;
```

Although the properties are exactly the same, this Typography came out different and smaller. How can I fix it? What am I doing wrong? Do I need to use something else except `component`and `variant`?

I also tried this but it didn't make a difference.

```
export const Typo = styled(Typography)`
  && {
    component: h1;
    variant: h5;
  }
`;
```

Comment: Hi, can you please mark the answer accepted if it helped you? Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only write CSS inside the styled body:

```
styled(Typography)`
  /* Only CSS here */
`
```

what you're doing is writing props in here which will not work. You can pass those props to your styled component and it will work just fine.

```
export const Typo = styled(Typography)`
    /* Write your CSS here */
`;

// Pass your props to Typo
<Typo component="h1" variant="h5" />
```

If you want to bind props with the Styled component and not worry about them when rendering the component, you can do it with `attrs()` method:

```
export const Typo = styled(Typography).attrs({
  component: 'h5',
  variant: 'h1'
})`
    /* Write your CSS here */
`;

// No need to pass props anymore, they are bind to this component
<Typo />
```

Comment: Just saw this. So, is there no way that I could remove the inline styling here ```<Typography component="h1" variant="h5">``` and move it into styled components? My main intention was to remove the details from wherever I'm calling them. Is it not possible?

Comment: Yes you can do that with `.attrs()`, I'll update my answer

Comment: I'm not sure why are seeing this, here's a working example. This might help: https://codesandbox.io/s/busy-payne-xmpw6?file=/src/App.js

Comment: ah yes, it works. Additionally, do you have an idea how we can change something like ```<Typography variant="h6" noWrap>``` since there's no value that we can assign to noWrap in the attributes.

Comment: a prop with no value is always considered a boolean `true`, so you can do `noWrap: true`